# The use of std::map find is throwing compiler error C2675 and I can't figure out why

Tags: c++, find, stdmap

Why is my find failing to compile for the class below?  Error reads:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2675   unary '++': '_Iter' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   PlayspaceForDataStructures  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\xtree 1259

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Tag
{
private:
    string name;
    map<string, string> attributes;
public:
    Tag()
    {
        name = "";
    }
    Tag(string inName)
    {
        name = inName;
    }
    Tag(Tag& inTag)
    {
        name = inTag.GetName();
        attributes = inTag.getMap();
        
    }
    string GetName() { return name; }
    void SetName(string inName) { name = inName; }
    void AddAttribute(string inName, string inValue)
    {
        attributes.insert(inName, inValue);

    }
    map<string, string> getMap() { return attributes; }
    string GetValueByName(string inName)
    {
        auto it = attributes.find(inName);
        if (it != attributes.end())
            return it->second;
        else return "";
        
    }

};
```

Comment: Which form of [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) are you trying to use with `attributes.insert(inName, inValue);`?  I'm guessing you wanted to pass that function a `std::pair<string,string>`.

Comment: Could just do `attributes[inName] = inValue;` as well. You should keep in mind that this is an unconditional overwrite where `insert` can fail if the key already exists. If that's important for you to know then you should use the return value from `insert`.

Comment: Thanks for catching this, will fix, but the compiler complains only when I add the auto it = attributes.find(inName) line.

Comment: I see now, it was complaining about the improper use of insert, even though the compiler error only happened whenever I added the find call.  How embarrassing.  I had a C++ job for years, but rarely had to use the STL.